# Is there a way to reverse mask the images produced by YOLOv8 object detection?

Tags: python, numpy, object-detection, image-segmentation, yolov8

I am planning to produce safe landing zones with my custom trained YOLOv8 model. I wish to reverse the masking of the output images of Yolov8 such as the photo provided: [Object detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLqR0.jpg).

The reverse masking aims to show the safe landing zones from the images, if possible mask it with green. Is there a tool that can help me achieve this? or specific functions fron Open CV. Please I badly need help

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Please give a Photoshop/GIMP mock-up of what the expected answer looks like. Also, please provide your original image you started with.